# jQuery.parseJSON returns null

Tags: jquery, json, node.js

I am passing valid JSON on the server side (using node.js) but not able to parse on the client side (using jQuery). `jQuery.parseJSON` returns `null`. Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Server side-

```
var message = [{key:"1", count:1},{key:"2", count:2}];
client.publish('update', JSON.stringify(message));
```

Client side -

```
socket.on("update", function(data) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    alert (obj); // returns null
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Can you check what's the `data` being received?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté thanks for editing my question. alert(data) returns Object.

Comment: Well, `JSON.parse` takes a string, so there's the problem. If you're on Chrome (or Firefox with [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/)), use `console.log(data)` instead of `alert` then press F12 to inspect the object properties. Either your JSON string is inside a property of the `data` object or `data` is the parsed object already.

Comment: Exactly! I tried the technique suggested by @JonathanLonowski . See my response in the thread below. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you try `console.log(data)` and post the output from the console? It is impossible to answer without that data. Check my comment above again for detailed instructions.

Comment: Yeah, comment out the buggy code then try `console.log(data)` again. `=]`

Comment: I see nothing on my console when `console.log(data[i].key)` is commented out!

Comment: No properties inside or arrow to extend that object? Then sometime went wrong before that. Maybe the client is receiving invalid JSON.

Comment: Problem solved! socket.io emits a key value pair (not an array of key value pair). I changed my implimentation and it works now! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> [...] now I get a new error message "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o"

That error usually means that `data` is already the `Array` parsed from the JSON. You can verify this [with `typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof):

```
console.log(typeof data);
// if `string`, then it has yet to be parsed
// if `object`, then it's already been parsed
```

So, you may not need to use `$.parseJSON()` or `JSON.parse()` and may be able to iterate `data`:

```
for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
    console.log('Key = %s, Count = %s', data[i].key, data[i].count);
}
```

---

And, the error comes from [`JSON.parse()` expecting a `String`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.12.2):

> 1. Let *JText* be ToString(*text*)

So, passing an `Array` of `Object`s to it will use [`.toString()`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.2) to produce:

```
"[object Object],[object Object]"
```

It'll start trying to parse this as another `Array` due to the leading `[`, but will find `object` invalid since JSON doesn't support identities.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Much appreciated. Applied changes suggested but still having problems. Below is more information.    

   alert(typeof data);  // returns Object
   alert (data.length); // returns undefined
   // Hard-coding l=2 for now
   for (var i = 0, l = 2; i < l; i++) {
   alert(data[i].key);  //Console error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot   read property 'key' of undefined 
   }

Intresting. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What version of jQuery are you using? From the `$.parseJSON` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/):

> Prior to jQuery 1.9, $.parseJSON returned null instead of throwing an
>   error if it was passed an empty string, null, or undefined, even
>   though those are not valid JSON.

Comment: I was using 1.7.1 . I just changed to 1.9.1 now I get a new error message "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o"

Comment: I have a feeling that `socket` is not a valid jQuery object.

Comment: socket libraries are included from node.js .

Comment: Ah, okay. I don't use `node.js`

Comment: @JonathanLonowski How can I get the key value pairs?